# How to use multiple models inside one viewset/serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 items inside my system that I have to use.But I am trying to develop a system which i have to get them inside one view and order them by "timestamp".

```
class CalendarEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarEvent
        fields = ("id","author",...)

class CalendarItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarItem
        fields = ("id","author",...)
```

I use ViewSet to regulate my models to paginate and filter them.

```
class CalendarItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = CalendarItem.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = CalendarItemSerializer
    filter_backends = [UserFilterBackend,DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filterset_fields = ['author']

class CalendarEventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = CalendarEvent.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = CalendarEventSerializer
    filter_backends = [UserFilterBackend,DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filterset_fields = ['author']
```

How can I use this system to merge 2 or models into one viewset or serializer like this?

Note:I know there are some answers for similar kind of questions in stackoverflow but my code structure is but different, I want to get some viewpoints

**Update**

So here is what i want to do:
-I am forming a feed page like facebook/instagram and combine multiple models inside one view.

-I can already do it with the viewsets above,but i want to now merge them.

-I want to sort each item by its timestamp and retrieve them inside JSON but inside one system, not like :

```
calendarevents:[] calendaritems []
```

but like:

```
calendarevent 1(created 2 mins ago)
calendaritem 1 (created 3 mins ago)
calendarevent 2(created 4 mins ago) 
calendaritem 2(created 5 mins ago)
```

I am happy to include more information,just ask.

Update 2:

```
class CalendarEvent(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='calendarevents')
    charfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    integerfield1 = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    charfield2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    charfield3= models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=64000)

class CalendarItem(models.Model):


    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='calendaritems')
    charfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    integerfield1 = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    charfield2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    charfield3= models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=64000)
```

Comment: One thing I get from your explanation is you want to merge both of these ModelViewSet. Can you please tell on what basis you want to get results for `CalendarItemViewSet`, and went to show results of `CalendarEventViewSet` .

Comment: If you can tell me the conditioning basis then we can merge them customizing under lying helper function of model view set.

Comment: I have updated the question,check it out.

Comment: If that is the case I will suggest writing your custom APIView because the model view set in its essence is supposed to be used for a single model. By saying that I mean you can do it but it is not the best practice to customize the model view set and get results as a merged view set results for two model. Using APIView set you can write your custom APIView if there is a need you can add Mxinins from DRF.

Comment: how? Thats why i am here to ask this

Comment: Check my answer as it is taking a long space to write and merge it. I hope it will help you in the right direction.

Comment: Can you share your full model and what common fields `CalendarEvent` and `CalendarItem` you want to display? You might want to have a look at [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) and use the parent class in your viewset.

Comment: @BrianDestura I can't share the full information of models but i gave the common fields they have under different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to approach this is to use [**`multi-table inheritance`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) to create a parent model for both `CalendarEvent` and `CalendarItem`, where the common fields they have can be defined in the parent:

```py
class CalendarFeed(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='calendarevents')
    charfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    integerfield1 = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    charfield2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    charfield3 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=64000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class CalendarEvent(CalendarFeed):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)


class CalendarItem(CalendarFeed):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Then you can just create a serializer and a viewset that captures all `CalendarFeed` like so:

```py
class CalendarFeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CalendarFeed
        fields = "__all__"


class CalendarFeedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = CalendarFeed.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = CalendarFeedSerializer
    filter_backends = [UserFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filterset_fields = ['author']
```

With these, you can list all `CalendarEvent` and `CalendarItem` via the parent `CalendarFeed`.

Comment: ```django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'CalendarItem' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'CalendarFeed'.```

Comment: Oh yeah you can just move `id` to the parent, or add another field as a parent link as described in the same section for multi-table inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the login using APIView and Generic APIVIEW

Here is one of the ways you can achieve what you are trying to achieve.

```
class GetCalenderEventAndItemsAPIView(APIView, GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    item_queryset = CalendarItem.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    event_queryset = CalendarEvent.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    item_serializer_class = CalendarItemSerializer
    event_serializer_class = CalendarEventSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['author']

    def get_paginated_query(self, _query_set):
        page = self.paginate_queryset(self.filter_queryset(_query_set))
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        return page

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        event_serializer = self.event_serializer_class(self.get_paginated_query(self.event_queryset),
                                                       many=True)
        item_serializer = self.event_serializer_class(self.get_paginated_query(self.item_queryset), many=True)

        response_results = {
            "calendarevents": event_serializer.data,
            "calendaritems": item_serializer.data

        }
        return Response(response_results)
```

It will get you in the right direction. Just play around above way of doing it.

Comment: `GenericAPIView is not defined` this is the error i get

Comment: Please import GenericAPIView from Django rest framework from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView, and from rest_framework.views import APIView

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases APIView, GenericAPIView`

Comment: you can remove APIview if it is creating an issue

Comment: `router.register(r'feedpage', GetCalendarEventAndItemsAPIView)`
 
It gives me this error now : assert queryset is not None, basename argument not specified, and could  \
AssertionError: basename argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `queryset attribute

Comment: These errors are related to routers as you are using routes instead you can try using URLs and paths. Please If further help needed you can getinto chat rooms or on my profile, and contact me via chats .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241784/discussion-between-umar-hayat-and-umarbeyoglu).